# Jquery function to save image from fileuploader on a button's click (In a dynamically created div)

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have created a `<div>` (say new div) with Ajax call and then append it to the existing `<div>` (say old div).

In new div, I have an `input [type=file]` and a button. On button click I want to save the image. I am using a jQuery function here.

My function is as follows:

```
function SaveData(evt) {
    var clientid = evt.id;
    $('#' + clientid + '').click(function() {
        var myval = $(this).closest('div.findvalues').find('input.filedata').val();
        alert(myval);
    });
}
```

But I am getting two errors:

1. `onclick` is working from 2nd click (no response for the first time).
2. I am getting this error `TypeError: evt.closest(...).closest(...) is null`.

HTML (this is html from browser, its generated after my Ajax call ):

```
<div class="col-md-15 col-sm-3 findvalues">
  <input type="hidden" value="../Documents/Raman" id="hdnRaman" name="documentNAME">
  <input type="hidden" value="74" id="hdn74" name="documentID">
  <input type="file" class="filedata" id="fuRaman" name="file[]">
  <input type="button" onclick="SaveData(this)" class="boldfontcss w3-btn uploaddata" value="Upload" text="Upload" id="btnRaman">
</div>
```

Comment: could you paste also your html? a sample piece

Comment: better if you edit your question is more readable

Comment: this is the html from browser, its generated after my Ajax call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try something like this?

```
$('.uploaddata').click(function() {
    var myval = $(this).parent().find('.filedata').val();
    alert(myval);
});
```

From the button, i search the parent, which is the main div-wrapper then i find the file with class filedata.

Comment: @SunilChaudhry could you please validate the response so if someone have the same problem can take this option as solution :)

Comment: Actually I had problem in my jQuery function, I called the click in onclick event but really thanks buddy.

Comment: @SunilChaudhry your welcome, and nice that you fixed also this problem